# After setting up route53 and alias name pointing to load balancer for naked domain "mypage.com", how can I redirect requests to www?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Do I need to set up my listener to redirect to www.mypage.com? How do I accomplish this?

Current issue: when I try to load mypage.com nothing happens, just times out.

update: I set up certificate for *.mypage.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you get certificate for mypage.com not just *.mypage.com. Also make sure to set up your listener to route from naked domain to www.mypage.com. This should work

Answer (score 1):

You should already have something like this pointing to the server or load balancer:

```
MYDOMAIN.com.   A   42.42.42.120
```

Add a CNAME record that points to the domain name not to the IP address or load balancer.  That is, to the left side of the A record not to the right side.

```
www.MYDOMAIN.com.   CNAME   MYDOMAIN.com.
```

Add additional A records as needed  (AWS might have done this for you already)

```
ipv4.MYDOMAIN.com.  A   42.42.42.120
```

These could be either A or CNAME, using an A record skips the second DNS lookup

```
ftp.MYDOMAIN.com.   CNAME   MYDOMAIN.com.
webmail.MYDOMAIN.com.   A   42.42.42.120
mail.MYDOMAIN.com.  A   42.42.42.120
```

For POP/IMAP incoming mail

```
MYDOMAIN.com.   MX (10) mail.MYDOMAIN.com.
```

Comment: I have an A record with alias turned on. The name is "mypage.com" and the alias points to the load balancer. Is this part correct? In addition do I create a cname record?

Comment: If you already have an A for mypage.com then you would not add a second one, just add the CNAME

Comment: yes, edited to be clearer.  You can leave out the ftp, webmail, etc. if you don't need them.

Comment: ok let me clarify what I have so far: A name record, "mypage.com" alias --> pointing to elb.  CNAME record, "www.mypage.com" no alias ---> pasted ELB dns value. Both saved now. Do I need to tweak the listeners in elb? Because when I go to mypage.com it doesn't redirect to https://www.mypage.com .  EDIT: in my ELB listeners I have https 443 setup and that has forward to my target group set up(which in turn points to my instance). Then I have http as well in listeners which points to my https 443 and redirect to my "original path/query"

Comment: CNAME points to mydomain.com not to the IP address or load balancer. that is to the left side of the A recond not the right side.